# Как изменить фон заголовка в QTreeWidget PySide2

Tags: python, qt-designer, pyside2, qss, qtreewidget

Я использую определённые стили для своей программы и хотел бы как-то изменить задний цвет в названии столбца (я обвёл, какой кусочек надо изменить).

Я пробовал задать background-color, но меняется всё, кроме этого кусочка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте применить таблицу стилей:

```
QHeaderView::section {
    background-color: #8ad8ca;
    color: #1b2b28;
    padding-left: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #6c6c6c;
}
QHeaderView::section:hover {
    background-color: #6eaca1;
    border: 2px solid #ca8ad8;
    color: #fff;
}

QTreeView {
    show-decoration-selected: 1;
    outline: 0;
}
QTreeView::item {
    color: #0d1514;
}
QTreeView::item:hover {
    background: rgba(80, 120, 242, 100);
    border-top: 1px solid #002cf2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #002cf2;
}
QTreeView::item:selected {
    background: rgb(80, 120, 242)
}
```

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tree = QTreeWidget()
        self.tree.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tree.header().setSectionsClickable(True)
        
        # Задайте заголовок заголовка дерева управления
        self.tree.setHeaderLabels(['Key','Value'])

        # Установите корневой узел
        root = QTreeWidgetItem(self.tree)
        root.setText(0, 'Root')
        root.setIcon(0, QIcon('images/android.png'))

        # задает цвет фона корневого узла
        brush_0  = QBrush(QColor(231, 176, 224))
        root.setBackground(0, brush_0)
        brush_1 = QBrush(QColor('#64cb85'))            
        root.setBackground(1, brush_1)

        # Установите ширину столбца дерева управления
        self.tree.setColumnWidth(0, 150)

        # Установить дочерний узел 1
        child1 = QTreeWidgetItem()
        child1.setText(0, 'child1')
        child1.setText(1, 'ios')
        child1.setIcon(0, QIcon('lena.jpg'))

        # задает состояние узла
        child1.setCheckState(0, Qt.Checked)
        root.addChild(child1)

        # Установить дочерний узел 2
        child2 = QTreeWidgetItem(root)
        child2.setText(0, 'child2')
        child2.setText(1, '')
        child2.setIcon(0, QIcon('im.png'))

        # Установить дочерний узел 3
        child3 = QTreeWidgetItem(child2)
        child3.setText(0, 'child3')
        child3.setText(1, 'android')
        child3.setIcon(0, QIcon('images/android.png'))

        # Загрузите все свойства и дочерние элементы корневого узла
        self.tree.addTopLevelItem(root)

        # Добавьте ответное событие в узел
        self.tree.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

        self.tree.expandAll()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tree)

    def onClicked(self, qmodeLindex):
        item = self.tree.currentItem()
        print(f'Key={item.text(0)}, value={item.text(1)}')


Stylesheet = '''
QHeaderView::section {
    background-color: #8ad8ca;
    color: #1b2b28;
    padding-left: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #6c6c6c;
}
QHeaderView::section:hover {
    background-color: #6eaca1;
    border: 2px solid #ca8ad8;
    color: #fff;
}

QTreeView {
    show-decoration-selected: 1;
    outline: 0;
}
QTreeView::item {
    color: #0d1514;
}
QTreeView::item:hover {
    background: rgba(80, 120, 242, 100);
    border-top: 1px solid #002cf2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #002cf2;
}
QTreeView::item:selected {
    background: rgb(80, 120, 242)
}
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet)   
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @ВаняДюльгер что не так?

Comment: У меня света сутки не было, вот только сейчас посмотреть зашёл)

Comment: @ВаняДюльгер бывают и нас такие проблемы.